# Are there drawbacks to selling buildings?

Tags: civilization-5

I've hit the end of the science tree in Civ V, so I want to divert as many resources as possible into other areas (wealth, culture, production etc).  I see that you can now sell buildings but if I sell off all my universities, schools, libraries, etc will I suffer any drawbacks?

I know that if I sell these buildings I'll get back some of the effort put into building them as gold, their maintainence cost is removed and their specialist slots are removed (which will cause the AIs to allocate specialists away from Science towards other goals instead) so it seems like an obvious thing to do.  But if I do it will it hurt my ability to produce high-tech items such as stealth fighters or death robots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you're no longer interested in science production, removing Libraries, Universities, Observatories, Public Schools, and Research Labs should be safe.

You'll lose out on:

- Science production from the buildings themselves and specialists
- Specialist contribution towards Great Scientists

I believe in some iterations of the Civ series there were high-level science buildings that aided in the production of the spaceship for the technology victory, (Civ4 had the [Laboratory](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Laboratory) building, for example) but I don't believe this is the case in Civ 5.

The only other concern is that researching Future Tech counts towards your score at the end of the game, if you're concerned with your score.

If you go this route, make sure you also check and make sure that you're not science focused in any of your cities, and that you aren't producing "Research" anywhere, since those will mean very little if your science production is nearly halted.

Comment: Civ V does have space ship factories, but they only accelerate space ship production, you can still build the parts without them.

Comment: @GordonM, yes, and they depend on factories and not research buildings.  In Civ4, the Laboratory increased spaceship production rate by 50%

Answer (score 3):

Here are the social policy downsides of selling those buildings and emptying those Science specialist slots:

Rationalism

- Humanism: +1 Happiness from every University, Observatory and Public School
- All Policy Bonus: +1 Gold from Science buildings

Commerce

- All Policy Bonus: +1 Gold from every Specialist

Freedom

- Civil Society: Specialists consume only half the normal amount of Food.
- Democracy: Specialist Population in Cities produce half the normal amount of Unhappiness

If you're not careful, you could wind up wrestling Unhappiness or Starvation.  You could make a budget shortfall worse (if you were already consuming science each turn to feed the deficit), but I don't think anyone is likely to go from a surplus to a shortfall by selling science buildings.

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't but it would eventually remove other bonuses given by those buildings, so take it in consideration.

In the whole Civ series it's almost never required to have a building to build an unit, except for a few very specific units.